# (Intro probability) time until first {event 1} preceded by at least 1 {event 2}, why is my reasoning not ok?

Tags: probability, poisson-process

Doing this exercise:

> Iwana Passe is taking a multiple-choice exam. You may assume that the number of questions
> is infinite. Simultaneously, but independently, her conscious and subconscious faculties are generating answers for her, each in a Poisson manner. (Her conscious and subconscious are always
> working on different questions.) Conscious responses are generated at the rate λc responses per
> minute. Subconscious responses are generated at the rate λs responses per minute. Assume
> λc != λs. Each conscious response is an independent Bernoulli trial with probability pc of being
> correct. Similarly, each subconscious response is an independent Bernoulli trial with probability
> ps of being correct. Iwana responds only once to each question, and you can assume that her
> time for recording these conscious and subconscious responses is negligible.

> (d) Determine the probability density function for random variable X, where X is the time
> from the start of the exam until Iwana makes her first conscious response which is preceded
> by at least one subconscious response

I'm trying to solve it with such reasoning:

C - time from the beginning until first conscious response

B - at least 1 subconscious response occurred during [0; C] time interval

$$
f_c(c) = λ_c*e^{-λ_c*c}
$$

Using Poisson PMF of number of k arrivals in a time interval t:
$$
P(B | C = c) = 1 - P(0\ subsconscious\ responses\ occurred\ during\ time\ interval [0; c]) = 1 - e^{-λ_s*c} 
$$

Thus:
$$
f_x(x) = f_c(x)*P(B | C = x) = λ_c*e^{-λ_c*x} * (1 - e^{-λ_s*x} )
$$

But my PDF of X doesn't match the one given in the answer (tested graphically). Why is this reasoning not correct? Answer is attached as image:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you seek to obtain $f_{X}$ by conditioning on $C$, the formula you should be using is $$f_{X}(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f_{X|C}(x|c)f_{C}(c)\mathrm{d}c$$ Here, $f_{X|C}$ denotes the conditional density of $X$ given the arrival time of the first conscious response. It's important to remember that $f_{X|C}$ is *not* a probability but rather a probability *density.*

If you're interested in finding the pdf of $X$ through conditioning, here is one way.

Fix any $x\geq 0$ and take $N$ as the total number of answers (either conscious of subconscious) produced on $[0,x)$. Notice $N\sim \text{Poisson}\left((\lambda_c +\lambda_s)x\right)$ and from the total law, $$\mathbb{P}(X>x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X>x|N=n)\mathbb{P}(N=n)$$ The event that $X>x$ given $N=n$ will only occur if all that conscious responses that occur in $[0,x)$ take place before any subconscious responses. Therefore, $$\mathbb{P}(X>x|N=n)=\sum_{k=0}^n\left(\frac{\lambda_c}{\lambda_c + \lambda_s}\right)^k\left(\frac{\lambda_s}{\lambda_c + \lambda_s}\right)^{n-k}=\frac{\lambda_s^{n+1}-\lambda_c^{n+1}}{(\lambda_s-\lambda_c)(\lambda_s+\lambda_c)^n}$$ We get that $$\mathbb{P}({X}>x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_s^{n+1}-\lambda_c^{n+1}}{(\lambda_s-\lambda_c)(\lambda_s+\lambda_c)^n}\cdot e^{-(\lambda_s + \lambda_c)x}\frac{[(\lambda_s + \lambda_c)x]^n}{n!}$$ Using routine calculus this sum evaluates to $$\mathbb{P}(X>x)=\frac{e^{-(\lambda_s + \lambda _c)x}(\lambda_s e^{\lambda_s x}-\lambda_c e^{\lambda_c x})}{(\lambda_s-\lambda_c)}$$ Taking a derivative and multiplying by $-1$ yields the density $$f_{X}(x)=\frac{\lambda_s \lambda_c}{\lambda_s - \lambda_c}(e^{-\lambda_c x}-e^{-\lambda_s x})$$ which is exactly the pdf provided in the solution key.

**Question:** I originally attempted to find a formula for $f_{X|C}(x|t)$ for $0 \leq t \leq x$ by using a recursive relation... $$\mathbb{P}(X>x|C=t)=\mathbb{P}(N_s(c)=0)\times \mathbb{P}(X>x-t)$$ where $N_s(c)\sim \text{Poisson}(\lambda_s c)$ is the number of subconscious responses provided in $[0,c)$. This led me to the functional equation $$f_{X}(x)=\int_0^x \lambda_c e^{-(\lambda_c + \lambda_s)t}f_{X}(x-t)\mathrm{d}t$$ Unfortunately for me, $f_{X}(x)=\frac{\lambda_s \lambda_c}{\lambda_s - \lambda_c}(e^{-\lambda_c x}-e^{-\lambda_s x})$ is *not* a solution to this functional equation. Can anyone help me understand why $\mathbb{P}(X>x|C=t)=\mathbb{P}(N_s(c)=0)\times \mathbb{P}(X>x-t)$ isn't valid? Maybe I'm overlooking something obvious. Thank you.